# Eclipse: Create preferences programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to create some preferences page programmatically. It works everything as expected when I trigger  the following code for the first time:

```java
    IPreferencePage page = new NewPreferencePage(test);
    page.setTitle("First Title");

    PreferenceManager pm = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPreferenceManager();
    PreferenceNode node = new PreferenceNode("node." + nodeName, page);
    pm.addToRoot(node);

    Shell shell = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
            .getShell();

    PreferenceDialog pd = new PreferenceDialog(shell, pm);
    pd.setPreferenceStore(Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());

    pd.create();
    pd.open();
```

The problem is when I try to access to the preferences from the standard mode (Window -> Preferences) an error occurs, and the node that I have created is null.
Also, when I trigger this code for the 2+ time, a new node is created and the previous appears as a blank line in the preferences list.

Anyone have some tutorial or some detailed information describing how to create this programmatically. I have searched in the web and tried different ways, but without success.

Or if anyone knows how to change the standard PreferenceDialog when the menu is triggered, I can try another solution.

This question is similar with this one:
[Eclipse: create preference page programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017001/eclipse-create-preference-page-programmatically) ,
but I was not able to solve it anyway.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I soved it by overriding the getPreferenceStore() in my preference page and it works. See the code below:

```
@Override
public IPreferenceStore getPreferenceStore() {
    return MarkerPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It did not work in my case. I add the PreferenceNode at the first time to the PreferenceManager. But the next time PreferencesDialog is opened, that node is still null.